# getting the current mouse cursor image in c++ or c

Tags: c++, c, winapi, handle, mouse-cursor

In my application I want to get the current mouse cursor to display it in an applet. for that I have to write a C or C++ function that returns mouse cursor as a buffered image.

(here I choose C or C++ because of the speed of execution. other than that I found c# code snippet that get the cursor as a bit map in this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12850/Capturing-the-Desktop-Screen-with-the-Mouse-Cursor.)

In msdn library there is a function that returns a handle to the current cursor. but handle can do nothing other than passing to a function. is there a function that returns the current cursor as a buffered image or can I get cursor image using handle itself?

Comment: [`GetIconInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648070(v=vs.85).aspx) looks like it's halfway to what you want. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830698/mouse-cursor-bitmap) seems to be doing about the same thing, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like: [GetCurPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

(There are a bunch of functions in the sidebar to look into also)

This article might also be of help: [C++ Programming: Easy Screen Capture Using MFC/ATL](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/article.php/c18347/C-Programming-Easy-Screen-Capture-Using-MFCATL.htm)

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you are able to figure it out from that, click the `^` button a bit above the tick :)